# Understand below SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

I need your help to understand below query can anyone help me to describe it, i wanted to know the role of **b.id is null** and **r.id is null** in below query if anyone can explain whole code then it would be great?

```
select l.id as start,
(
    select min(a.id) as id
    from sequence as a
        left outer join sequence as b on a.id = b.id - 1
    where b.id is null
        and a.id >= l.id
) as end
from sequence as l
    left outer join sequence as r on r.id = l.id - 1
where r.id is null;
```

Comment: As a hint, in the subquery `b.id is null` means keep all records from `sequence` which did _not_ match to anything in the join.  You might do well to add some sample data along with a description of what the query is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

The query is joining two tables (in this case the same table but it does not matter) using an outer join.

if we have

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t2.d
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.a = t2.a
WHERE t2.a is null
```

This means it returns a set of records with all those from table1, however its possible there will not be a joined record from table2 for every record in table1.  If there isn't the table2 fields are returned as null so the the WHERE clause is effectively saying return me all records from table1 where we do not have a join record in table2.

In your example where it joins onto itself you are looking where there is not a next/previous record (depending upon which way you are looking at it) based upon the id e.g. if id = 5, then there is not a record with id = 4

Overall the sql as a whole looks like its returning the consecutive id ranges in the sequence table.

Answer (score 0):

This query returns your "islands"of your sequence, i.e. `start` and `end` of continuos id intervals.

You can read more on `gaps` and `islands` here: [Special Islands](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/09/t-sql-queries/special-islands) and here [The SQL of Gaps and Islands in Sequences](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)

Answer (score 0):

The query is finding islands of consecutive numbers, outputting the start and end of ranges where all consecutive numbers are there, so for the set if numbers

{1,3,4,5,6,9,10}

I would expect

1,1

2,6

9,10

to be selected

The outer query starts by finding number (N) that cannot join to a record holding N-1, detected by r.id is null
The sub query then finds the next highest number (M) that does not join to a record holding M+1 (detected using b.id is null)

so in my example 3 does not have a '2' to join to, meaning 3 begins a range.  The first number >= to that with no subsequent record is 6, which has no '7' to make a join to